# Can azure app service delete folders that created by another instance?

Tags: azure, service, directory, temp

We have Azure app service that is configured auto scale up/down depending on some criteria.

1. Application hosts in app service will download big files from Azure blob storage to
   local 'D:\home' to process
2. Application will clean up those temp files after successfully/failed process.
3. However, when app service scale down, the temp files downloaded by scaled down app service are not cleaned up, and eventually run out of space for those remaining app service.

Questions:

1. Can remaining running app service delete those files/folders that were downloaded/created by another app service instance (and those app services instance are gone because of scale down)?  All of those files/folders downloaded/created be different app service instances are in the same 'D:\home'.
2. If there is a way to detect app service is shutting down, clean up those temp files/folder before it finally shut down?

Answer (score 0):

1- There's no ready to use feature like that. You can try implementing one using alerts from Azure Monitor and / or create a WebJob that will keep monitoring the temp folder

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-classic-portal

2- as far as I know, there's no event that is raised for that.